# Load class from the internet/filesystem in Android

Tags: java, android

Is it posible to load a class from the internet in Android? My app would download a class with some data, save it on sdcard, and then load the class. I want this because loading data via classloader is much faster then from a file.

Comment: Faster, how ? A java classfile has to be read like any other file and adds the overhead needed to validate the class. With what code do you read your files that it is slower?

Comment: I need to load an array of strings, I don't know why, but simply loading it from a file is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always load data from your SDCard to your application.

But thinking logically you wont be able to add a class just like that since it needs to be complied again to an apk after which you must install it on the respective device for your code to get reflected on your applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

The normal way this is done is with a server that sends data to you in XML or JSON format. You then parse that data and build the corresponding object, from that data that the server sent you.